Why does my Dockerized React Native Web (Expo) display the nginx welcome page?
I can run my app locally via npx expo start -w.
When I build the docker image and run it, I only see the nginx welcome screen. I've seen some of the other posts regarding a similar issue but none of their fixes have worked for me.
Note: The web app is using file based routing. I have ios and android directories as well. I'll attach a screenshot of the directory structure at the bottom in case it's at all relevant.
Here's the Dockerfile:
FROM node:16.17.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npx expo export -p web

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

Here's the nginx.conf
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}

Here's my build command:
docker buildx build -t gcr.io/my-project/my-app .
Here's my run command:
docker run --name my-app -p 8080:80 -d gcr.io/my-project/my-app
app.config.ts web object:
  web: {
    bundler: 'metro',
    output: 'static',
    favicon: './assets/images/favicon.png',
  },

asyncRoutes is set to true for web in all environments (although the app doesn't even seem to be running, so this might be irrelevant).
Directory structure:

